# Seems like python requests proxies does not change my ip address

Tags: python, python-requests, request

I'm wonder why

```
requests.get(
    url="https://www.myip.com/",
    proxies={
         "http": "100.100.100.100:8080",
         # "https":  "115.136.33.52",
    },
    headers = {
      "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Safari/537.36",
      },
)
```

this code does not change my ip address into "100.100.100.100"
Am I missing some information about proxy?

Isn't it changes my ip to one another just by filing the dictionary?

If I'm wrong how can I change my REQUEST IP ADDRESS into an IP ADDRESS what I want.

just like if I set my proxy to "1.1.1.1:8000"
then the website thinks "1.1.1.1:8000" sent a request.

Comment: You did not set a https proxy, but connecting to a https website.

Comment: requests.exceptions.SSLError:

Comment: error when I set https proxies

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an HTTPS proxy. To overcome the SSLError add this line of code:

```
requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_.DEFAULT_CIPHERS = 'ALL:@SECLEVEL=1'
```

Comment: What i'm curious about is  if I set my proxy to "1.1.1.1:8000" then the website thinks "1.1.1.1:8000" sent a request?